# When Does docker-compose call the Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm a little bit confused, I have a docker-compose file where I am trying to install `apache` and `mariadb`...

```
web:
   image: php:5.6-apache
   volumes:
        - ./:/var/www/html/
   environment:
     - ALLOW_OVERRIDE=true
   ports:
     - "80:80"
   links:
     - db


db:
  image: mariadb
  restart: always
  volumes:
    - ./docker/db:/var/lib/mysql
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    MYSQL_USER: admin
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: test
    MYSQL_DATABASE: database
  ports:
    - "8889:3306"
```

Everything works fine until I try and do some URL rewriting in Apache and I get this...

```
web_1  | [Thu Apr 12 16:55:31.646473 2018] [core:alert] [pid 18] [client 172.17.0.1:34330] /var/www/html/applications/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

So I follow some online instructions to add a `Dockerfile` with...

```
FROM php:5.6-apache

MAINTAINER Raphael Mäder <ra@mader.com>

RUN a2enmod rewrite

ADD . /var/www/html
```

But it doesn't fix the problem. In fact even when I add an error into the file like this...

```
FROM php:5.6-apache

bleurrrrgggghhh

MAINTAINER Raphael Mäder <ra@mader.com>

RUN a2enmod rewrite

ADD . /var/www/html
```

And then call `docker-compose` everything boots up fine. So I know that the docker file can't be getting called. Even when I remove the image with `docker-compose rm` and restart it still nothing.

Am I getting confused about how I can run get the Dockerfile command working?

Comment: when you say `image:` in your compose file the Dockerfile is never used, it uses just image, yoi have to change it to `build: .` or something similar.

Comment: The issues is not with  the docker-compose file as it is building the image you specified. You need to create dockerfile only when you want to create your own image. No need to write `Dockerfile` if you are using the image  from public repo. Error is in your  rewrite rule try to fix it there

Answer (score 0):

Once the image is built, it won't be built again, unless you explicitly want it to be rebuilt. With docker-compose, you pass the `--build` to force the image to be rebuilt.

`docker-compose up --build web`